# Передача большого массива через TCP

Tags: c++, linux, qtcreator, tcp

Требуется передать большой массив int'ов с клиента на сервер, однако передается только 16370 элементов массива. Это примерно равно 64 кБ, что является максимальной длиной одного пакета ТСР, если я правильно все понял. Аналогичный код, только с использованием WinSock2 работал на windows, но при переносе на Linux и смене библиотеки сокета, получилось то, что получилось.

UPD.
Я понимаю, что можно вручную разбить на куски и высылать их, но насколько я понял, так упадёт скорость передачи, а смысл этого всего был в получении максимальной скорости(просто это часть кода).

### Сервер

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create a socket
    int listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == -1)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &hint.sin_addr);

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    // Tell Winsock the socket is for listening
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    // Wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t clientSize = sizeof(client);

    int clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];      // Client's remote name
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];   // Service (i.e. port) the client is connect on

    memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST); // same as memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);
    memset(service, 0, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }

    // Close listening socket
    close(listening);
    int size = 32000000;
    int *arr = new int[size];

        // Wait for client to send data
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, (char*)arr, (size * sizeof(int)), 0);
        if (bytesReceived == -1)
        {
            cerr << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
        }

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client disconnected " << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 9000;i < 18000;i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << endl;
        }

        cout << arr[99999] << endl;




    // Close the socket
    close(clientSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

### Клиент

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

//8521

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //  Create a socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //  Create a hint structure for the server we're connecting with
    int port = 54000;
    string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    //  Connect to the server on the socket
    int connectRes = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connectRes == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int size = 32000000;
    int *arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    cout << arr[31999998] << endl;

        //      Send to server
        int sendRes = send(sock, (char*)arr,(size * sizeof(int)), 0);
        if (sendRes == -1)
        {
            cout << "Could not send to server! Whoops!\r\n";
        }

    //  Close the socket
    delete [] arr;
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте пересылать в цикле, разрезая на фрагменты разумного размера

Comment: Так вы же не дочитали до конца. Анализируйте bytesReceived, если маловато - повторяйте в цикле. Сколько байт ожидать? Посылайте в самом начале отдельным полем. recv() возвращает управление, в общем, когда хочет. Это и в мане написано, его сто́ит осмыслить.

Comment: В смысле не дочитал до конца? Зачем высылать размер, если я заранее знаю его?

Comment: @Mike, ты не прав... если сокет не неблокирующий, то `send()` блокирует пока буфер не будет отправлен полностью (или соединение не разорвётся)...

Comment: *или вызов не будет прерван сигналом, или не случится ещё чего-то необычного...

Comment: Кстати, если не дождавшись, пока сервер прочтет все уже вроде бы отправленные данные закрыть сокет, то можно потерять хвост, который еще не ушел в сеть из буферов ядра. Т.е. в протокол обмена лучше добавить read перед close на стороне клиента.

Comment: @avp, это всё же относительно редкая ситуация... да и на практике в большинстве протоколов последнее слово всё равно обычно за сервером.... а он не заботится, если связь с клиентом неожиданно пропала в последний момент...

Comment: В TCP нету явного признака конца пакета, поэтому признак конца желательно добавлять в пакет самостоятельно. Либо почитав протокол - разобраться как в протоколе реализован признак "длинна пакета".  Для http - чаще всего это Content-Length. В FTP, SMTP - возврат каретки считается концом пакета. Для SSL - заголовке пакета его длинна.

Comment: @avp только перед чтением надо бы не забыть про shutdown. Или же, как альтернативный вариант, можно SO_LINGER настроить.

Comment: На стороне сервера вы же его заранее не знаете. Ну, или, если считаете, что знаете, то и вызывайте recv()/select() в цикле, пока не прочитаете в сумме столько байт, сколько нужно.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потоковый сокет (`SOCK_STREAM` вообще и tcp в частности) представляет собой непрерывный поток данных разделённый на произвольные сегменты, так что отдельные сообщения могут приходить частями или слипаться. При чтении из такового может быть выдан произвольный объём данных меньше запрошенного, так что при приёме любого количества данных больше одного байта следует использовать цикл чтения. В типовом варианте с обработкой ошибок он будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
size_t dataSz = size * sizeof(int);
void *data = (void *)arr;
bool failed = 0;

while (dataSz>0) {
  ssize_t recvSz = recv(clientSocket, data, dataSz, 0);

  if(recvSz>0) {
    dataSz -= recvSz;
    data += recvSz;
  } else if (recvSz==0) { // Удалённая сторона закрыла соединение
    cerr << "Connection was shutdown before data read was finished" << endl;
    failed = 1;
    break;
  } else { // recvSz<0
    if (errno == EINTR) {
      continue; // recv() был прерван сигналом: продолжить чтение.
                // В примитивных примерах этот случай обычно опускают,
                // но, вообще говоря, его желательно иметь в виду.
    } else {
      cerr << "Error in recv(): '" << strerror(errno) << "'. Quitting!\n" << endl;
      failed = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (failed) {
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

В совсем примитивных случаев можно обойтись и простой передачей в `recv` флага `MSG_WAITALL`:

```
ssize bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, (char*)arr, (size * sizeof(int)), MSG_WAITALL);
```

---

Для отправки такой цикл обычно не обязателен т.к. если сокет не является неблокирующим, то `send`, когда данные не помещаются в буфер, по умолчанию блокирует дальнейшее исполнение до полного копирования данных в буфер ядра (и отправки всех предыдущих данных).

---

Стоит также иметь в виду, что и `recv()` c `MSG_WAITALL`, и `send()` могут считать/записать в сокет меньший объём, если соединение будет разорвано. И эту ситуацию стоит отдельно обрабатывать.

А ещё если оные будут прерваны сигналом, то они вернут управление недочитав/записав запрошенный объём, так что, строго говоря, в достаточно сложном случае цикл чтения/записи всё равно будет необходим...

---

#### Мелкие придирки

- Вообще говоря, при передаче по сети нет гарантии что размер типа `int` или порядок байт на разных хостах будет одинаков, так что, вообще говоря, при записи в сокет стоит использовать сериализацию.

Comment: TCP протокол имеет контрольную сумму, и номера пакетов, данные внутри TCP протокола могут быть повреждены с той вероятностью, к которой неустойчивой является контрольная сумма в пакете. Меньше прийти может, но это будет говорить о том что "недошёл хвост". Середина выпасть или пеперутаться местами - не может, потому что пакеты пронумерованы. Если бы так было - сайты бы плохо читались, потому что http протокол поверх TCP, и не проверяет контрольную сумму (в 99% случаев). Проверяется длинна (Content-Length) и то невсегда

Comment: @nick_n_a, к чему это всё?

Comment: " по сети нет гарантии что размер типа int или порядок байт будет одинаков" - это неправда. Порядок байт будет соблюдён. Не пугайте людей.

Comment: уточнил... про порядок байт конечно имелось в виду «на разных хостах»...

Comment: Вы путаете устройство сети с пакетами TCP и с сокетом. Сетевые пакеты могут и правда прийди в любом порядке (попутаться местами). Но это вы заметите если пишите драйвер или под ардуино сырые пакеты ловите. При использовании сокета - сокет отдаёт данные в том порядке, в котором они отправлены. Реализовано это с помощью протокола TCP. При использовании протокола TCP или TCP-сокета - порядок байт - сохранится.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я ни где не писал писал про изменение порядка получения пакетов... а замечание про порядок байт на разных хостах это к тому, что запихивать хостовый массив `int`'ов в сокет как есть — плохая идея... когда-нибудь он придёт на какой-нить arm или ещё-какую be архитектуру и получится неожиданный результат...

Answer (score 8):

recv выдает меньше данных чем отправил клиент и его нужно обязательно дочитывать

```
int *arr = new int[size];
char *pointerarr = (char*)arr;

int toread = (size * sizeof(int))

do {
    int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, pointerarr, toread, 0);
    pointerarr += bytesReceived;
    toread -=  bytesReceived;
} while (bytesReceived!=0 || toread<=0) // или другой признак конца передачи
```

Comment: забыл читаемый размер уменьшать по ходу цикла...

Comment: Да, наверное, но оно и так сработает. Ядро сбросит хвост на последней итерации потому что клиент сразу отключается

Comment: только вот если кто-то передаст больше данных, то будет выход за границы массива...

Comment: Исправил этот момент.